# Error -What am i doing wrong in this sql query?

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to update values in a table from the same table using a particular condition but it is not running

I have tried it using "WITH"

```
update my_table as res1
set res1.my_column = (select res2.my_column from my_table as res2
                      where res2.parent_id is null and res2.is_company = true)
where res1.parent_id=res2.id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try SQL below:

```
update my_table as res1 set my_column = res2.my_column from my_table res2 where res1.parent_id = res2.id and res2.partner_id is null and res2.is_company;
```

Comment: hi.. thnx for ur answer....i tried it using your sql query.. it is returning the same error that  'missing FROM-clause entry for table "res2" ' i was getting from my query

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the type of SQL server, but generally an UPDATE from a SELECT takes a particular syntax:

[How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server)

Comment: thnx for replying & sorry i forgot to mention.. the server is postgresql